# Groupbox border issue

Tags: vb.net, winforms, groupbox

I have a vb app and i recently noticed a strange problem with Groupboxes on one of the forms

The problem is, i can see through the borders of groupboxes, so let's say i opened the generated executable and place it over my desktop with nothing behind, i can clearly see parts of the wallpaper i have (check the image below)

[image]

Now the funny thing, i have not modified any of the properties of those groupboxes and i believe the problem started after i added the following to my app.config

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

I added that part in order to be able to compile code using SQLite..

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to duplicate what you are showing, is by setting the Forms AllowTransparency property to `True` and having the `TransparencyKey` set to `ControlLightLight`. You may want to double check for something similar in your program.

Comment: i i can't find AllowTransparency but im assuming it's True, other than that for some reason i had TransparencyKey set to some greyish color, i am wondering what triggered that? Any keyboard shortcut maybe? Because i never used this before -.- Anw, thanks i wouldn't have guessed but now i know :)

Comment: @DanyKhalife It's hard to tell, but I am glad to have been of help